org.hibernate.mapping.JoinedSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass, two @Id
I am migrating xml configuration to annotations.
I have a class:
@Entity
@Table(name = "INSTRUMENT_OFFERINGS")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class InstrumentOffering extends HibernatePersistentObject
        implements Serializable, Comparable<InstrumentOffering>
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "instrument_offerings_sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "instrument_offerings_sequence", sequenceName = "instrument_offerings_sequence")
    @Column(name = "INSTRUMENT_OFFERINGS_ID")
    private Integer instrumentOfferingId;

and second which is extending previous:
@Entity
@Table(name = "INSTRUMENT_OFFERINGS_HISTORY")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "INSTR_OFFERINGS_ID")
public class InstrumentOfferingHistory extends InstrumentOffering {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "instrument_history_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "instrument_history_seq", sequenceName = "instrument_history_seq")
    @Column(name = "INSTRUMENT_HISTORY_ID")
    private Integer instrumentHistoryId;

I know that it's failing because I have two @Ids. It's unbelivable that this construction was working in xml configuration but how should I handle it now?
InstrumentOfferingsId is different than InstrumentOfferingsHistoryId and can't be shared.
INSTRUMENT_OFFERINGS has Id and INSTRUMENT_OFFERINGS_HISTORY should has it's own Id. Plus INSTRUMENT_OFFERINGS_HISTORY can have one INSTRUMENT_HISTORY_ID but it's @ManyToOne to INSTRUMENT_OFFERINGS.
I should create third class without @Id which both classes will extend and both will have their own @Id? Is there different way?

InstrumentOfferingHistory is a sort of audit table or has a separate lifecycle than InstrumentOffering? In this case separating InstrumentOfferingHistory from InstrumentOffering may give you a better entity handling

every change to InstrumentOffering is written into InstrumentOfferingHistory so tables are nearly the same but I can have InstrumentOfferingId many times in table InstrumentOfferingHistory depending on number of changes. You mean to not extend InstrumentOffering at all?

yes. separate concerns: historical data get a way and current data has its own lifecycle

that's how I did it - InstrumentOfferingHistory doesn't extend InstrumentOffering anymore.
